# Can any PEG grammar be parsed in linear time?

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-grammars, parsers

On [the Wikipedia for PEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) it is claimed:

> Any PEG can be parsed in linear time by using a packrat parser, as described above.

However, packrat parsers can't handle left recursion.

You can eliminate any left recursion to create another grammar that recognizes the same language as the left-recursive one, however, those grammars are not equivalent because they do not result in the same derivation (e.g. a left-associative `expr -> expr '+' expr` becomes right-associative after left recursion elimination).

After doing some research I found [a resource](http://www.vpri.org/pdf/tr2007002_packrat.pdf) that can parse (indirect) left-recursive PEG, but it's not linear time.

So, is the claim on Wikipedia incorrect, or is there a linear time algorithm that can parse **any** PEG?

Comment: The same article claims that "*PEGs cannot express left-recursive rules*", so it is at least consistent.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: It's not just wikipedia. Bryan Ford's original thesis says (p. 25) "In TDPL, while right recursion works in much the same way as it does in a CFG, a left-recursive definition is considered erroneous, because its interpretation under TDPL rules leads to a degenerate self-reference." (TDPL is top-down parsing language, aka PEGs).

Comment: The claim was indeed incorrect - I have rewritten the paragraph in question. Ford's article explicitly distinguishes PEGs without left recursion (calling them *well-formed* PEGs) and his master's thesis suggests that well-formed PEGs cannot recognize all languages that arbitrary PEGs can recognize, but doesn't do into the matter in great detail. The Wikipedia article claims that all left recursion can be eliminated, but even if this is true, it may not be a linear-size expansion.

Comment: @reinierpost The expansion size does not matter for the linear time requirement, because the runtime is measured _in terms of the input string_, not the size of the grammar. The main problem with eliminating left recursion is that the derivation tree is not the same before eliminating left recursion.

Comment: Hmm ... good point.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it needs to be shown that left factoring elimination as described in the dragon book (section 4.3.4), which Ford refers to, is correct for PEGs.

Comment: As to the derivation tree, can't you make the transformation leave annotations that allow you to reconstruct the original tree?

Comment: @reinierpost I _believe_ you should be able to post-process the generated AST using tree rotations on certain patterns, followed by some node merging to restore associativity, at least for direct left recursion. [Example (proper)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Left-recursive-parse-of-a-double-subtraction.png) and [eliminated](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/Right-recursive-parse-of-a-double-subtraction.png).